# I can't load bower/yarn dependencies on my rails projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to manage my fron-end with **yarn** or **bower** tools to download the packages directly from the github and I'm having some troubles to call the files from `application.css` or `application.js`.

So I created a simple rails project to examine the main problem carefully. I did the changes written in this short article (https://sheerdevelopment.com/posts/using-yarn-with-rails)

*1. use the command to generate the yarn **package.json** file and **components** folder:*

```
yarn add font-awesome --modules-folder ./vendor/assets/components/
```

*2. add this line on **assets.rb***

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "components")
```

*3. change **application.css** to **application.scss** and add:*

```
*= require font-awesome/scss/font-awesome
```

obs: I tried without this last modification too and with the path font-awesome/css/font-awesome that we have.

> couldn't find file 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome' with type
>   'text/css' Checked in these paths:
>   /home/fillype/code/modusss/blog/app/assets/config
>   /home/fillype/code/modusss/blog/app/assets/images
>   /home/fillype/code/modusss/blog/app/assets/javascripts
>   /home/fillype/code/modusss/blog/app/assets/stylesheets
>   /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.1/lib/assets/javascripts   /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.0.rc1/lib/assets/compiled   /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.1.0.rc1/lib/assets/compiled
>   /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts

```
Extracted source (around line #13):
11 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
12 *
13 *= require font-awesome/scss/font-awesome
14 *= require_tree .
15 *= require_self
16 */
```

What I noticed is that the Rails is not looking for the assets inside the components' folder despite the fact that I specified this path on `assets.rb` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way:

The error message didn't appear anymore after this:

1. insted of adding this on **assets.rb**:

   Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "components")
2. I attached this line of code on **application.rb**:

.

```
module Blogapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "bower")
  end
end
```

Now the page started to load but with some squares [] on the icons place. Then I knew that [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem has helpers to call the fonts so I changed the way the fonts was being called by the file `bower/font-awesome/scss/_path.scss` in this way:

before:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff2'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
//  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); // used when developing fonts
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

after:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
  src: font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff2'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}') format('truetype'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
//  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); // used when developing fonts
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

---

Obs:

The main problem was clearly the `assets.rb` that is not the right place to specify the assets paths.

After I successfully added the font-awesome like I explained, then I added **bootstrap** in a very simple way:

1. download from the command line:

   bower install bootstrap-sass-official --save
2. only adding this three lines of code on `application.scss` (*we must have to rename from **.css** to **.scss** to work!*) as it is told from [bootstrap-sass github page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) (but not everything that it is prescribed).

   $icon-font-path: "bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

   @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";

   @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";